# Proving root of polynomial (constructable numbers)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $\theta$=$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{p})$+$i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{p})$. Prove that $\theta$ is a root of $h(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+x+1$.

I have no idea of how to start this. Do I need to factor out the root and show it goes to 0?

Comment: $\theta$ is an odd name for it, call it $z$. Then $z^p-1=0$ but $z\ne 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

First, show that $\;\theta^p=1\;$, for example using de Moivre's Theorem, or putting the number in exponential form.

Next, verify that $\;x^p-1=(x-1)(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+x+1)\;$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\theta$ in exponential form,
$$\theta=e^{2\pi i/p}\ ,$$
and sum a geometric series.

Comment: But that does not help if I don't know p does it?

Comment: Did you actually sum the GP?  If so, you should see that your answer can easily be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to show that $\theta^{p-1} + \theta^{p-2}+ \ldots + 1 =0$.

Maybe try first for $p=3$. You can use some concrete values:
$$ \cos \frac{2\pi}{3}= -\frac{1}{2}\\
\sin \frac{2\pi}{3}= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
You could then try $p=5$, use some concrete values
$$\cos \frac{2\pi}{5}=\frac{-1+ \sqrt{5}}{4}\\
\sin \frac{2\pi}{5}= \sqrt{\frac{5 +\sqrt{5}}{8}}$$

I am not sure this works for $p=7$, one may need some other ideas.